# OpenCV.js Assertion failed in detectMultiScale

Tags: javascript, html, opencv

So I'm relatively new to JavaScript and I'm attempting to learn OpenCV.js for a web app I'm working on. I've been following tutorials like [this](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/df/d6c/tutorial_js_face_detection_camera.html) to try and understand how it works.

However, I've been getting the error below where the haar cascade file isn't being loaded and I can't seem to fix it.

```
Error: Assertion failed (!empty()) in detectMultiScale, file /build/master-contrib_docs-lin64/opencv/modules/objdetect/src/cascadedetect.cpp
```

I've looked for resolutions to this problem and most people suggest that you should use the full directory when loading a cascade file. I've tried referencing the file directly and using the full file path, either way doesn't seem to work for me.

This is how I've attempted load the file.

```
let classifier = new cv.CascadeClassifier();

// Load the haarcascade file
let utils = new Utils('errorMessage');
let faceCascadeFile = 'http://localhost/eeu8cb/xml/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml';
utils.createFileFromUrl(faceCascadeFile, faceCascadeFile, () => {
    classifier.load(faceCascadeFile)
});

// Checks if the haarcascade file has failed to load
if(!classifier.load(faceCascadeFile)){
    console.log('failed to load file.')
}
```

I've done some error checking which confirms the file isn't being loaded. Any help would be appriciated, cheers.

Comment: Have you tried to load from relative path?

Comment: As mentioned below if you are loading the file from http:// you need to use some web server so in node http.server

Answer (score 0):

Some month ago i worked right on OpenCV.js using those tutorials and i remember there was a problem on loading files while not using HTTPS protocol, i solved my problem using IIS Express.

So try using a web server.

Comment: I've always been using a web server (xampp) but it wasn't https. I've managed to get https working but it is still unable to load the file.

Comment: Check if you can access the Haar_cascade.xml file from your web browser querying it.  Try using a relative path for file loading as Pari Baker suggested.

Comment: I can access the cascade file through the web browser just fine and using a relative path doesn't seem to work. I've done some more messing around and I think the problem is with the createFileFromUrl, after some checking it doesn't actually execute that statement.

Comment: If you try loading it this way?
classifier.load('xml/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml');

Comment: Maybe the xml file is the problem?